# GCM Push notification RECEIVE Not working

Tags: android, notifications

The server is sending push notification to the app using device id. The app has to receive and show notification to user. The app is already registered in GCM and push notification is working fine for IOS. Now testing with android. The android app has to just receive the notification sent by backend. But the message is not received.

The log I collected for GCM is as follows:

```
11-11 17:06:09.139 10265-10265/? I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil: getPushTypeList : [SPP, GCM]
11-11 17:06:10.729 3506-4220/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
11-11 17:06:14.249 10265-10298/? I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil: getPushTypeList : [SPP, GCM]
11-11 17:06:14.329 10265-10300/? D/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PCWHandler: [ensureRegistration] - MG registered : GCM
11-11 17:07:27.389 3506-3915/? V/BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{19bd6d1 u0 com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE} DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{38a314d8 4539:com.google.process.gapps/u0a13}
11-11 17:07:27.439 3506-4581/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.AutoBackupGcmTaskService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
11-11 17:08:34.659 10676-10676/? I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil: getPushTypeList : [SPP, GCM]
11-11 17:11:54.029 4539-6262/? I/GCM: GCM message GSYNC_TICKLE 0:1447222313784217%e7a71353318775cf
11-11 17:11:54.179 3506-4634/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gsf/com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.GCMIntentService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
11-11 17:11:54.579 3506-4643/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.gcm.http.GoogleHttpService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
11-11 17:14:54.039 4539-6262/? I/GCM: GCM message GSYNC_TICKLE 0:1447222413012818%e7a71353318775cf
11-11 17:14:54.069 3506-4683/? D/ActivityManager: retrieveServiceLocked(): component = com.google.android.gsf/com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.GCMIntentService; callingUser = 0; userId(target) = 0
```

Below is my Manifest file

````````````````````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.clinicloud.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.clinicloud.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.clinicloud.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.GlobalDataAccess"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GCMTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gcmtest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- for Gingerbread GSF backward compat -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.clinicloud.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="com.clinicloud.app.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>```````````````````
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->

    </application>

</manifest>
````````````````````

Below is my GCMListener Service

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"**********************************************************Inside onMessageReceived =>");
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    Log.d(TAG,"**********************************************************Send notification message =>"+message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
        Log.d(TAG,"*************************************************************************Message =>"+message);
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
        Log.d(TAG,"**************************************************************************Message downstream =>"+message);
    }

    sendNotification(message);

}
```

I have added compile **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'** in my dependencies

Please let me know if I miss anything... I could not understand why GCM Listener service is not called.

Comment: refer this link its working with me http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Comment: You most likely entered the hash of your release key when you setup gcm. Try to sign your app with your release key.

Comment: Nope... I have not set up any gcm. I just gave the dependency. Thats it. Can you pls tell me is there anything else that needs to be done.